# how to know which imports and modules are available

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to reduce the size of my application by cutting down on some imports and one of the things I've learned is that doing things like `import {foo, bar, foobar} from library` can create a much larger final bundle and instead it is better to do

```
import foo from library/foo
import bar from library/bar
// etc
```

My question is how do I know which individual modules are available? is it standard that if this works

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
```

that something like this should also work as well ?

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'react/proptypes'
```

How do you know which modules and exports are available in a project in order to target just ones that you want to avoid doing `import * from module`

Comment: How do you know it in projects that don't use ES6 modules (but e.g. CommonJS modules)? The same applies here.

Comment: "*creates a lot of unnecessary bloat*" - not sure what you mean?

Comment: As always: read the docs of the library you're importing. Either they document that you can import some of their submodules, or you can't (shouldn't).

Comment: @Bergi by not explicitly importing only what you need it imports the entire library so the physical size of something like a webpack bundle can be potentially much larger. To me anyway, documentation in a lot of libraries, even widely used projects, lacks the guidance how to only import certain modules or how they are laid out without going through source. I was thinking maybe there was a standard for it that I was not aware of.

Comment: @FelixKling If I was using CommonJS id be asking the same question. Are there standards? Or are you just at the mercy of the library to provide good documentation as to what's available or do you just have to read the source to know what you can and can't require/import

Comment: "Or are you just at the mercy of the library to provide good documentation as to what's available or do you just have to read the source to know what you can and can't require/import" <- this

Comment: @ThrowsException Open the npm_modules folder, and check to see if it either has `<module-name>/<import-name>.js` or `<module-name>/<import-name>/index.js`. If it has one or the other, you can import them. Webpack 2.0, however, will prefer that you use ES6 `import { foo } from "bar"` syntax, as it will then tree-shake any code from the library that hasn't been statically imported in such a way.

Comment: @ThrowsException: Well, you could use a better bundler like [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) to prevent that - it figures out all this dynamically :-)

Comment: @Norguard Yea I just read about that tree shaking that will hugely beneficial when 2.0 comes out.

Comment: @Bergi I would If we hadn't just moved our entire bundling to from gulp to browserify to webpack but If I switch bundlerers one more time I'm quiting.

Comment: @Norguard if you want to make your last comment as an answer I can accept that. it seems either source or docs is the only way to know and it seems bundlers are working to alleviate this issue so that my answer for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the npm_modules folder, and check to see if it either has `<module-name>/<import-name>.js` or `<module-name>/<import-name>/index.js`.
If it has one or the other, you can import them.

Webpack 2.0, however, will prefer that you use ES6 syntax.

```
import { foo } from "bar";
```

It will then tree-shake any code from the library that hasn't been statically imported (or referenced by the static code) in such a way.

Answer (score 2):

> That something like this should also work as well ?

No. It is up to the module creator. You are most likely using a `node_module` for react and the fact that `react/proptypes` is available points to the fact that there is a file `node_modules/react/proptypes.js` in the package.

This means its entirely up to the module author.